# Does a left group action on a principal bundle induce an action on associated vector bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $G\hookrightarrow P\xrightarrow{\pi}M$ be a principal $G$-bundle with right action $\cdot $ and suppose we are also given a left action $\rho: U\times P\rightarrow P$ of some group $U$  on $P$. Everything is smooth. Note that since left and right actions commute, for $u\in U$ the map $\rho_u=\rho(u, ):P\rightarrow P$ maps fibres to fibres and induces a map $\bar \rho_u$  on $M$. I am interested in the case where $\bar\rho_u$ is *not* the identity on $M$.

> If $V$ is a vector space, $\kappa$ a representation of $G$ on $V$ and $E=P\times_\kappa V$ is the associated vector bundle with projection $\pi_E$, does $\rho$ induce in any natural way an action $\hat \rho$ of $U$ on $E$ so that the map $\hat\rho_u:E\rightarrow E$ is a vector bundle map (that is $\hat\rho$ maps fibres to fibres and $\hat\rho:E|_{\pi_(p)}\rightarrow E|_{\pi_(\rho_u(p))} $ is linear) which covers $\bar\rho_u$?

It seems to me that a suitable map $\hat\rho_u$ would be of the form
\begin{equation}
\hat\rho_u([p,v])=[\rho_u(p),L_u(p)v],
\end{equation}
with $L_u(p):V\rightarrow V$a linear map. In order for $\hat\rho_u$ to be well defined we need $L_u(p\cdot h)=\kappa(h)^{-1}L_u(p)\kappa(h)$. The action on the fibres of $E$ is linear and $\hat\rho_u$ maps fibres to fibres and covers $\bar\rho_u$ as
\begin{equation}
\pi_E(\hat\rho_u([p,v]))=\pi_E([\rho_u(p),v])=\pi(\rho_u(p))=\bar\rho_u(\pi(p))=\bar\rho_u(\pi_E([p,v])).
\end{equation}

In general it seems to me that the only "preferred" choice for $L_u$ is to take $L_u(p)=\mathrm{Id}_V$ (or a multiple thereof) for all $p$, so that
\begin{equation}
\hat\rho_u([p,v])=[\rho_u(p),v].
\end{equation}
If $U$ is a subgroup of the centre of $G$ we can also take $L_u(p)=\kappa(u)$, still independent of $p$.

> First, am I saying anything stupid? And second, are there other natural ways of defining an induced action of $U$ on $E$ with the required properties?

EDIT: I have found the following related, but not equivalent question
[Group actions and associated bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396988/group-actions-and-associated-bundles?rq=1)
asking about induced actions on *sections* of an associated bundle. Sadly it is without answers too...